# How can I elegantize this brute-forcish jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML table [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/kbqsmedt/3/) that, in the first column of "Shift Details" in the "shift 1" section, has a "Hide N" select element:

```
  <TR>
  <TD align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="30">
    some date
  </TD>
  <TD align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="10">
    shift 1
  </TD>
  <TD align="center" valign="middle" >
      <label>Hide </label>
    <select id="hideselector">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
      </select>
  </TD>
```

Based on which option is selected, my jQuery hides labels below it, which are defined this way:

```
  <TD align="center" valign="middle" >
      <label id="jl1">job Loc 1</label>
  </TD>
```

The quasi-Hobbesian jQuery is nasty and brutish, but unfortunately not short:

```
$('#hideselector').change(function () {

    $('#jl1').removeClass('hide');
    $('#jl2').removeClass('hide');
    $('#jl3').removeClass('hide');
    $('#jl4').removeClass('hide');
    $('#jl5').removeClass('hide');
    $('#jl6').removeClass('hide');
    $('#jl7').removeClass('hide');
    $('#jl8').removeClass('hide');
    $('#jl9').removeClass('hide');

    var hidecount = $('#hideselector').val();
    if (hidecount > 0) {
        $('#jl1').addClass('hide');
    }
    if (hidecount > 1) {
        $('#jl2').addClass('hide');
    }
    if (hidecount > 2) {
        $('#jl3').addClass('hide');
    }
    if (hidecount > 3) {
        $('#jl4').addClass('hide');
    }
    if (hidecount > 4) {
        $('#jl5').addClass('hide');
    }
    if (hidecount > 5) {
        $('#jl6').addClass('hide');
    }
    if (hidecount > 6) {
        $('#jl7').addClass('hide');
    }
    if (hidecount > 7) {
        $('#jl8').addClass('hide');
    }
    if (hidecount > 8) {
        $('#jl9').addClass('hide');
    }

});
```

The jQuery above works, but I'm hoping there's a more concise/terse way of accomplishing the same thing, especially since I will ultimately need 84 very similar blocks of code (7 days X 3 Shifts X 4 Job Locations per shift).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery can perform actions on entire groups of elements at once, so instead of calling `removeClass()` on each cell individually, you can call `removeClass()` once on a selector that captures all the elements.

```
var cells = ["#jl1","#jl2","#jl3","#jl4","#jl5","#jl6","#jl7","#jl8","#jl9"];
$(cells.join(",")).removeClass('hide');
```

Getting the element IDs into an array would let you refactor your code as follows:

```
$('#hideselector').change(function () {
    var cells = ["#jl1","#jl2","#jl3","#jl4","#jl5","#jl6","#jl7","#jl8","#jl9"];
    $(cells.join(",")).removeClass('hide');
    var hidecount = $('#hideselector').val();
    var i = -1;
    while(i++ < hidecount){
        $(cells[i]).addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

I wouldn't stop there, though. If you have control over the HTML, I'd add some selectable attribute other than the ID (such as another class name or a `data-` attribute) to the elements you want to grab. Then instead of maintaining lists of element IDs, you'll just have to maintain a shorter list of classes/attributes/whatever. You might even consider offloading the storage of those attributes onto the select elements themselves, so you can have one onchange function to handle all of the selects.

```js
$('[data-shift]').change(function() {
  var cells = $("[data-lbl='" + this.getAttribute("data-shift") + "']");
  $(cells).removeClass('hide');
  var hidecount = this.value;
  var i = -1;
  while (i++ < hidecount - 1) {
    $(cells[i]).addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid forestgreen;
}
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE COLS="3" id="sceduleTbl" name="sceduleTbl">
  <COLGROUP min-width="20%"></COLGROUP>
  <COLGROUP min-width="15%"></COLGROUP>
  <COLGROUP min-width="15%"></COLGROUP>
  <COLGROUP min-width="15%"></COLGROUP>
  <TR>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <B>SHIFTS</B>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" colspan="4">
      <B>SHIFT DETAILS</B>
    </TD>
  </TR>

  <TR>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="10">
      shift 1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label>Hide</label>
      <select class="hideselector" data-shift="shift 1 loc 1">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
      </select>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label>Hide</label>
      <select class="hideselector" data-shift="shift 1 loc 2">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
      </select>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label>Hide</label>
      <select class="hideselector" data-shift="shift 1 loc 3">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
      </select>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 1">job Loc 1</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 2">jobLoc2</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 3">jobLoc3</label>
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 1">job Loc 2</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 2">jobLoc2</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 3">jobLoc3</label>
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 1">job Loc 3</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 2">jobLoc2</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 3">jobLoc3</label>
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 1">job Loc 4</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 2">jobLoc2</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 3">jobLoc3</label>
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 1">job Loc 5</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 2">jobLoc2</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 3">jobLoc3</label>
    </TD>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 1">job Loc 6</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 2">jobLoc2</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 3">jobLoc3</label>
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 1">job Loc 7</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 2">jobLoc2</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 3">jobLoc3</label>
    </TD>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 1">job Loc 8</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 2">jobLoc2</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 3">jobLoc3</label>
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 1">job Loc 9</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 2">jobLoc2</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label data-lbl="shift 1 loc 3">jobLoc3</label>
    </TD>
  </tr>

  <TR>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="10">
      shift 2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>

  <TR>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="10">
      shift 3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    $('#jl' + (i+1)).removeClass('hide');
}
var hidecount = $('#hideselector').val();
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(hidecount > i)
    {
        $('#jl' + (i+1)).addClass('hide');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#hideselector').change(function () {

   for(i = 1; i < 10; i++){
       $('#jl' + i).removeClass('hide');
   }

   var hidecount = $('#hideselector').val();

   for(j = 0; j < 9; i++){
       hidetarget = j+1;
       if(hidecount > j){
           $('#jl' + hidetarget).addClass('hide');
       }
   }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer to use the HTML from your fiddle, with the only change being removing the id "hideselector", and adding a class "hideselector", and duplicating the hideselctor for the second shift.

Because you didn't have labels in your second shift, I have the hideselector hiding the entire TD rather than the labels.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.hideselector').change(function() {
    var hidecount = $(this).val();
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    var locs = tr.nextAll().slice(0,9);
    locs.find('td:nth-child(1)').removeClass('hide');
    locs.slice(0, hidecount).find('td:nth-child(1)').addClass('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid forestgreen;
}
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE COLS="3" id="sceduleTbl" name="sceduleTbl">
  <COLGROUP min-width="20%"></COLGROUP>
  <COLGROUP min-width="20%"></COLGROUP>
  <COLGROUP min-width="15%"></COLGROUP>
  <COLGROUP min-width="15%"></COLGROUP>
  <COLGROUP min-width="15%"></COLGROUP>
  <COLGROUP min-width="15%"></COLGROUP>
  <TR>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <B>DATE</B>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <B>SHIFTS</B>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" colspan="4">
      <B>SHIFT DETAILS</B>
    </TD>
  </TR>

  <TR>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="30">
      some date
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="10">
      shift 1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label>Hide</label>
      <select class="hideselector">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
      </select>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label id="jl1">job Loc 1</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label id="jl2">job Loc 2</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label id="jl3">job Loc 3</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label id="jl4">job Loc 4</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label id="jl5">job Loc 5</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label id="jl6">job Loc 6</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label id="jl7">job Loc 7</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label id="jl8">job Loc 8</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label id="jl9">job Loc 9</label>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>

  <TR>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="10">
      shift 2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      <label>Hide</label>
      <select class="hideselector">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
      </select>
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>

  <TR>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="10">
      shift 3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc1
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc2
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc3
    </TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="middle">
      jobLoc4
    </TD>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

bingo's answer froze jsfiddle (twice); this derivation of anuraag's works, though:

```
$('#hideselector').change(function () {    
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $('#jl' + (i + 1)).removeClass('hide');
    }
    var hidecount = $('#hideselector').val();    
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (hidecount > j) {
            $('#jl' + (j + 1)).addClass('hide');
        }
    }    
});
```

### UPDATE

Jake Cigar's answer, over at jQuery Forum, was even more elegant, even a little Joan Fontaine-ish:

```
$('#hideselector').change(function () {
  var hideCount = $(this).val();
  $('.d1s1j1').addClass('hide').slice(hideCount).removeClass('hide');
});
```

I had to add the "d1s1j1" class for this to work, but it's a small price to pay for such statuesque elegance.